# If $\{h_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a basis of an Hilbert space, is it possible $\inf_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \|h_m\| = 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be an Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\{h_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an its basis.

Is it possible that $\inf_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \|h_m\| = 0$

Thanks.

Comment: There are several possible meanings of "basis" in this context.  But for any of them, if you take a basis and multiply each of the vectors by nonzero scalars, it remains a basis...

Comment: maybe I understood, i.e. $\frac{1}{n}e_n$ is a basis and its $\inf =0$? ($e_n$ standard basis of $\ell^2$)

Comment: Yes, that's a good example.

Comment: ok @NateEldredge thanks so much for yuor suggestion

Comment: One problem is that if you mean an algebraic basis, then no Hilbert space has a countable algebraic basis (meaning indexed by $\Bbb N$). If you mean Hilbert basis, then $\|h_m\|=1$ for all elements. So you must mean Schauder basis or some other more exotic type of basis.

Comment: thanks @s.harp I mean a Schauder basis